# Java on double: How to properly implement 'd' or 'D if there are many numbers or an expression to calculate?

Tags: java, double

It's said that we should put 'd' or 'D' after the number when you're creating a double variable. But what if I'm calculating many numbers.

```
double div = (6 % 4) / 10;            // result 0.2
System.out.println("answer: " + div);          // output: 0.0
```

Obviously, I will get an unexpected answer which is supposed to be 0.2 NOT 0.0... Now if I put 'd' or 'D' after the numbers, I will get a proper answer.

```
double div = (6d % 4d) / 10d;            // result 0.2
System.out.println("answer: " + div);          // output: 0.2
```

Should I put 'd' on all numbers in one expression when using double variable? or putting 'd' in one number is enough?

```
    double div = (6 % 4) / 10d; //0.2
```

Comment: *Should I put 'd' on all numbers in one expression when using double variable? or putting 'd' in one number is enough?* - why don't you try it and see?

Comment: `double div = (6 % 4) / 10.0;` no need for a `d` or a `D`. BTW, `myDouble` and `div` appear to be different variables.

Comment: In an expression you only need to put a D or d or .0 on any one of them. That causes the whole expression to be avaluated in floating-point.

Comment: @user207421 Incorrect. If you only do it on `10`, then `6 % 4` will be calculated as `int`, not `double`. The result will still be correct, but your statement that "whole expression" is evaluated as floating-point is wrong.

Comment: As others have said, any 1 or 2 or all 3 of them will do, in this case. Which you do is entirely up to you. Everybody will have their own opinion on the matter, but there is no accepted standard, so I've voted to close the question as primarily-opinionated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use dot with numbers or one of them 
Result = (6 % 4) / 10.0; 
Resoun: dividing int / int = int , otherwise int / double = double